# Draggable Overview map re-positioning when TOC toggled

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, esri

I am using JQuery UI layout, ESRI Javascript API, and JQuery. I have my overview widget embedded in a JQuery "draggable" div. My issue is the following: When dragged on my map the "draggable" overview map positioning (which position was set to absolute in CSS) becomes relative to the west layout (TOC) border.So,  when the west pane (TOC) is toggled the position of the overview map changes automatically. Is there a way to have my draggable element stay at an absolute position?

I have previously posted a similar question on the [ESRI forum](https://geonet.esri.com/message/403105#403105)

You can access my map here:

`http://134.186.111.22/AG_Sandbox/layout-master/demos/Map-Widget-Panel-carousel-BasemapList.html#`

To toggle my overview map, just click on the white arrow located at the top right corner of my map.

To toggle the west panel (TOC), just click on red button located at the bottom right corner of the map.

Any help is welcome.
Thank you,
Alex

Comment: Hi, how about constrain movement of your drag gable widget within the browser window, so that it never flyies out of scope.

Comment: did you just fixed it on your demo page ?

Comment: No I did not fix it. I will update my public web map tomorrow, but it seems like constrain movement did not work for me. I will let you know when it is updated.

Comment: this is happening because your draggable panel 'left' css property is > then the width of the map on right hand side. This will also happen of you just re-size the left panel or pull it towards right. I also made a similar apps and had these problems before, its crazy and behave weird on diff browsers. Now i only use maps as full size on screen and every panel (left or right) as absolute overlay on it. never had any problems after that.

Comment: Oh thank you for the explanation! I am now thinking that absolute positioning of panels for maps are the way to go. too bad because I kind of like to have the user being able to resize panels as wished. I wish there was an easy work around to that "problem".